# What does the Auto Hotspot setting do on the Apple Watch?

Tags: apple-watch

When taking a look at the Apple Support article that explains how to manually connect an Apple Watch to Wi-Fi (https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT209071), the page makes a mention to a setting entitled "Auto Hotspot". I haven't been able to find any other references to this setting - would somebody be able to explain what it does?

Answer (score 1):

A hot spot is when another device with cellular data broadcasts Wi-Fi connectivity.

This setting allows you to automatically join those Wi-Fi, prompt you to join them or disables joining them.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Just out of interest, do you have any further information/documentation on how this feature works - for example, how does the Apple Watch differentiate between hotspots and standard Wi-Fi networks?

Comment: That would make a great follow on question @elliott94